# Transformar variáveis em Cookie com JS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, cookies, geolocalização

Podem em ajudar por gentileza estou tentando pegar a localização que vem da geolocation e transformar em cookie para ler com php e salvar no MySql mais sou meio leigo e nao estou conseguindo

código abaixo.

'''

if ('geolocation' in navigator){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        document.cookie = lat=position.coords.latitude;
        document.cookie = long=position.coords.longitude;

    },  function(error){
        console.log(error)
    })
}else{

    alert('Não foi possivel obter sua localização')

}

'''

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -4):

**Explicação geral**

Para criar um cookie com Javascript, usa-se o comando:

```
document.cookie = 'nome_do_cookie=Valor do cookie';
```

Para consultar um cookie no PHP, usa-se o comando:

```
$variavel = $_COOKIE['nome_do_cookie'];
```

**Explicação aplicada ao seu código**

Pelo que eu entendi do seu código, você quer salvar um cookie com a chave (nome) long. Então por isto usa o código:

```
document.cookie = long=position.coords.longitude;
```

Para consultar o seu cookie no PHP, basta usar o comando

```
$long = $_COOKIE['long'];
```

Comment: O `$_COOKIE` será vazio se ele não fizer uma requisição com o cookie recém-salvo.

Comment: isso ai quando eu tento puxar o cookie ele vem vazio ele não vem o cookie com as coordenada de longitude e latitude do geolocation